# Производительность LINQ и кэширование

Tags: c#, linq

Есть следующий код:

```
using System.Diagnostics;

class A
{

    public int Count { get; set; }
}

var rnd = new Random();

var lst1 = new List<A>();
var lst2 = new List<A>();

for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
{
    lst1.Add(new A { Count = rnd.Next(10000) });

    if (i % 3 == 0)
    {
        lst2.Add(new A { Count = rnd.Next(10000) });
    }
}

var sw = new Stopwatch();

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    sw.Start();
    var res1 = lst2.Where(i => !lst1.Select(l => l.Count).Contains(i.Count));
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine(res1.Count() + " " + sw.Elapsed);
    sw.Reset();
}
```

Первая итерация цикла for при вычислении res1 всегда выполняется существенно медленнее, чем следующие, т.е. после первой итерации результат LINQ кэшируется? И почему если вынести lst1.Select(l => l.Count) внутри for в отдельную переменную результат будет только хуже в плане скорости?

Comment: код, что вы привели, не скомпилируется. Вы тестируете какой то другой код.

Comment: + вы не понимаете что происходит в коде. Первый запуск скорее всего долгий, так как CLR надо перед запуском скопилировать код или процессору надо прогреть кеш. Я к тому, что у вас подход к замерам изначально неверный. Чтобы что то замерить, вы можете использовать [BenchmarkDotNet](https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet), ну, и, LINQ, конечно, ничего не будет кешировать - нет смысла в этом. Исходники функций LINQ вы можете глянуть [здесь](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,15)

Comment: также скорость работы может зависеть даже от флагов компилятора, в дебаге оно может одно показывать, в релизе с оптимизациями от компилятора - другое

Comment: беглое гугленье привело [вот сюда](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p-vSd_r33ac), самому некогда глядеть, но надеюсь вам поможет видео

Comment: и да, вы же не в отладчике смотрите время? Вы же скомпилировали это в exe файл в релизе и запускаете этот файгл несколько раз из консоли, так?

Comment: Попробуйте перед вашим кодом (перед всем вообьще вашим кодом, сразу в начале Main функции) поставить вот это `Enumerable.Range(0, 1000).Select(x=>new A { Count =  x}).ToList().Where(i1 => !Enumerable.Range(0, 100).ToList().Select(l => l).Contains(i1.Count));`, у меня после этого первый ваш запуск уже стал недолгим. То есть либо нужные методы LINQ моей строчкой скомпилировались, либо кеш прогрело или чтото типа того произошло.

Comment: @tym32167, спасибо за комментарии, для тестов использовал RoslynPad, поэтому код без main фунцкии

Comment: @tym32167 да, действительно, после добавления Enumerable.Range(0, 1000).Select(x=>new A { Count = x}).ToList().Where(i1 => !Enumerable.Range(0, 100).ToList().Select(l => l).Contains(i1.Count)); результат практически сравнялся

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как уже написал в комментариях tym32167, одна из причин - [JIT-компиляция](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/JIT-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F) кода [CIL](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language).

То есть при исполнении вот этой строки:

```
var res1 = lst2.Where(a => !lst1.Select(l => l.Count).Contains(a.Count));
```

сперва компилируются все эти методы: `Where`, `Select`, `Contains`. Классы `List<A>`, `A` и его свойство `Count` уже использовались выше по коду, поэтому они уже скомпилированы.

Что важно: недостаточно просто вызвать эти методы, например, так:

```
var list = new List<string>();
var test = list.Where(a => a == null).Select(a => a).Contains(null);
```

Результат замеров от этого не изменится. Хотя, казалось бы, использованы именно эти методы, но нет, у них другая сигнатура, а именно: с параметром `List<string>`.

А если взять наш класс `A`:

```
var list = new List<A>();
var test = list.Where(a => a == null).Select(a => a).Contains(null);
```

то это сразу скажется на результате замеров со `Stopwatch`.

---

А теперь самое важное. Вот эта строка:

```
var res1 = lst2.Where(a => !lst1.Select(l => l.Count).Contains(a.Count));
```

**ничего** не делает (JIT-компиляция не в счёт). Здесь просто создаётся linq-запрос.

А выполнение этого запроса выполняется при вызове метода `Count()` в этой строке:

```
Console.WriteLine(res1.Count() + " " + sw.Elapsed);
```

Это так называемые lazy evaluation (ленивое вычисление) и deferred execution (отложенное выполнение).

Увеличьте количество итераций (размер списка) на порядок в самом первом цикле:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
```

и это сразу станет заметно на глаз. Паузы между итерациями будут по много секунд, а замеренное время `sw.Elapsed` - доли миллисекунд.

---

Добавлю ещё вот что. Всё сказанное относится к Linq To Objects - запросам поверх `IEnumerable`.

Но есть ещё и Linq To Sql (Entity Framework и т. п.) - запросы поверх `IQueryable`. Они конструируются на клиенте, а выполняются на сервере. И вот тут уже действуют другие правила. План запросов может кэшироваться на сервере и прочее.

Comment: хех, а я проглядел где автор стопает замеры, хорошо подмечено, однозначно плюсик :)